# (View.INVISIBLE) before Timer.sleep() not working

Tags: android, timer, sleep, invisible

I have several buttons I want to make INVISIBLE for a short while then make them VISIBLE again. The (View.INVISIBLE) before Timer.sleep() does not work. I have yet to figure this out. Any ideas?
Thanks, Steve

```
private void commonBtnHandler(Button btn) {
    try {
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Thread.sleep(250);
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are so sure about the `View.INVISIBLE` does not work? The thread is sleeping for only 250 milliseconds. Its just a blink.

Comment: it won't work since you are blocking the UI thread, which is going to make the view invisible. Try using `Handler.postDelayed()` to delay the `btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` for 250 ms

Comment: I think this is inside a `Handler` already. If it is not, then your comment is correct. .

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `Thread.sleep()` on the UI/main thread. It will cause the UI to freeze & `ANR`

Try :

```
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 250);
```

Also `250 ms` is a very small amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.

I tried all the suggestions with a 3000 millisecond delay but still did not see a blink.

Also, I was wondering if I was blocking the UI thread. I thought the INVISIBLE would complete before the sleep() took effect.

Summary: I wrote a loop to make the call 10 times. The delay seems to be ignored in all cases. I appreciate everyone’s help. It looks like I need to rethink how this should work. I wouldn’t think this would be much different than how a game programmer would insure synchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing this issue in another way I did not INVISIBLE the button but temporarily changed the color using MotionEvent within a setOnTouchListener. When pressed the button changes color and when released reverts back to the original color. Works great!

```
    mBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch ( event.getAction() ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightOrange));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     new Thread() {
     public void run() {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}.start();
```

always put the runOnUiThread when need to change the UI in runtime, This is helps to you.